# Is it "safe" to mine with your cpu on a laptop for a long time?

Tags: mining-hardware, cpu-mining

I am currently trying to use the CPUMINER program on a Chromebook (using Linux) with its CPU for educational purposes. The Chromebook has four cpu cores.

I would like to know if it is safe for the computer to be mining Bitcoins for a long time (ex: a whole day) using all four cores. Would the CPU be damaged? Should I only use some of the four?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it overheats there's no problem with nonstop mining. I'd suggest installing something like [CoreTemp](https://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) to view internal temperatures. You should adjust its number of cores used until all of the temperatures can be considered low enough. How low? 70°C should be fine. 100°C isn't very nice I think. There's no exact limit, but you can search online.

Overclocking? I can't comment if mining nonstop on an overclocked CPU is healthy for your computer. You might need to reduce the temperature by even more.